# Making a container to fill it with content?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a container to fill it with content (mostly text) but i don't know where to start. i am trying to make it look like [[this]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAkTY.jpg)

the width, height, background-color etc. is not really important.

```css
img {
   width: 300px;
   height: 90px;
    
}
    
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
}
    
    
li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    border-color: #87CEFA;
    width: 200px;  
}
    
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
    
li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF51;
}
    
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" />
    
    <ul>
       <li><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
       <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
       <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
       <li><a href="D.html">D</a></li>
       <li><a href="E.html">E</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried / did it helped ? if so, please consider UV / accept the answer you used and that helped you most, as people know your question no longer needs help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, you can change the `.gray-container` values as you like

```css
.gray-container {
  background:lightgray;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin-top:20px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-color: #87CEFA;
  width: 200px;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF51;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" />

  <ul>
    <li><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="D.html">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="E.html">E</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="gray-container">
    <h1>123</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> reference: [MDN < length > VH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

The use of wiewport is supported by most browser and has a good compatibility.
In your case, you can add a grey container in the main div.

**CSS**

```
.graydiv {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 75%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100vh; // that's the trick
background-color: #ccc;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" />

<ul>
   <li><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
   <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
   <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
   <li><a href="D.html">D</a></li>
   <li><a href="E.html">E</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="graydiv">
123
</div>

</div>
```

You can then adapt to your needs, playing with margin and padding.

**NOTE**: to make sure, if no conflict with other css style, I recommand that you use :

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```